# Binary string from decimal number in SQL

Tags: sql, binary, hana

I'm working on a problem in SQL that needs to convert a decimal number into a binary string (8 and 32bit respectivily depending on some conditions).

I'm using SAP HANA, so i'm limited to the HANA SQL dialect.

So far i've come to:

```
SELECT
bitand(32832, 1)/power(2,0)||
 bitand(32832, 2)/power(2,1)||
  bitand(32832, 4)/power(2,2)||
   bitand(32832, 8)/power(2,3)||
    bitand(32832, 16)/power(2,4)||
     bitand(32832, 32)/power(2,5)||
      bitand(32832, 64)/power(2,6) ect... 
FROM DUMMY;
```

For an 8 bit number this should go up to power(2,8). A 32 bit number, however, requires 32 power(2,n) terms which I find rather nasty.

Is there some way, a method or SQL-function, that converts an number into a n-bit binary string?

Comment: There’s no specific feature in HANA/SQL that performs this kind of conversion. What is the problem that should be solved by a string representation of a binary number?

Comment: IOT devices that generate a decimal number, where the ones(1s) in the binary representation, represent a type of event.

Comment: I see. Well, the testing for set bits is done via `BITAND` like you already doing it. What I still not see is why a conversion to string is necessary here; matching up against the known event type bit-pattern requires only to perform `BITAND` with the respective numbers.